# Using message bus with promises and for DI/IOC

Tags: dependency-injection, architecture, inversion-of-control, eventemitter, message-bus

In my app I want to use "local" message bus in a particular way (extended event emitter/observer/dispatcher):

1. In some cases I want to use it for DI/IOC.
   I mean that some component will be registered as a producer for some message type.
   For example API client can register some methods as producers: (pseudocode)

```
bus.producers.register("topic/entity/get", ({id}) => entityClient.get(id));
```

Other component will post message in the bus:

```
bus.post("topic/entity/get", {id: 123});
```

and then consume the produced result;

*What are the problems with this approach?*
Note: consumer component will have declarative metadata config with all messages in consumes and produces.

2. I want to use promises for consume results.
   It is not directly related to DI/IOC - it is about handling the "output of message handlers".
   *So is it OK to consume bus like this*:

```
// get first produced (normal case)
const entity = await bus.getAsyncFirst("topic/entity/get", {id: 123});
    
// collect all entities from all producers
// rare case?
    
const entities = await bus.getAsync("topic/entity/get", {id: 123});
```

?

producer implementation just need to return value for consumer.

*What are potential pitfalls of this?*
*Or it is better to use generators for collecting all produced output (instead of Promise)*
*Shoult I post message to bus as a result (instead of just returning result)*. Something like

```
bus.producers.register("topic/entity/get", ({id}) => {
    const result = entityClient.get(id);
    bus.post("topic/entity/get/result"); // *is it better? why?*

});
```

I can't find examples of such using of message bus.